# Resources to learn how to design user access control?

Tags: java, access-control

I am working on a java project requires user access control, can anyone recommend me articles, books or related open source projects on how to design a good user access control system?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache Syncope Project](http://syncope.apache.org/) there are lots of interesting codes there. beside you may use it as a IDM of your application!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Spring ACL](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html) as a mature one. Here is tutorial http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-security-3-full-acl-tutorial.html